# mod_rewrite problem: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f matches even when REQUEST_FILENAME shouldn't (fully) match

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

For some reason this rule

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./rewrite.php?p=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

doesn't work for URLs like this http://site.com/index/var/val 
All other URLs work but this doesn't. It starts working when I either remove !-f
 part or rename index.php file located in the root to something else (e.g. test.php). So somehow site.com/index seems to be equal to site.com/index.php in the eyes of mod_rewrite? The files are located in the root so there shouldn't be any other (upper) .htaccess files involved. This doesn't happen to index only, for example if I create /something.xml, test.com/something/... will suddenly stop working. This happens on some servers only.

Does anyone know why this could be happening?

PS. /index directory is not present on this server

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The faulty module is [mod_negotiation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_negotiation.html), not mod_rewrite.

In debian :

```
a2dismod negotiation
```

**Edit:**

To be a little more specific this is the effect of **Multiviews**, handled by mode_negotiation. So you could keep the module and remove the MultiViews handling with:

```
Options -MultiViews
```

From documentation:

> A MultiViews search is enabled by the MultiViews Options. If the server receives a request for /some/dir/foo and /some/dir/foo does not exist, then the server reads the directory looking for all files named foo.*, and effectively fakes up a type map which names all those files, assigning them the same media types and content-encodings it would have if the client had asked for one of them by name. It then chooses the best match to the client's requirements, and returns that document.

Answer (score 0):

I've also solved this problem by removing the MultiViews keyword from the

```
<Directory>
```

section from my server configuration.

Hope this helps.

I believe the `${REQUEST_FILENAME}` aproaches the file as if it was served to a browser directly.

I had a similar problem with this:

- `/content/detailed-page` (Rewritten URL and parsed by php)

The file was returned to me the same way as:

- `/content/detailed-page.html` (real file)